# Two masters simultaneously?

Tags: masters, france, sweden

I am from Germany and about to finish my second bachelors degree (two different fields). And am now considering options for masters studies. Now i know that in Germany i can study two masters simultaneously and it generally does not matter too much if i need say three years to complete both instead of the two years advocated.

I would like to study at a good university in another country where tuition fees for EU citizens are rather small/zero.

Now is it possible to enroll in two master degrees simultaneously in France, Sweden, Norway, Denmark or other countries fullfilling the criteria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer with respect to Sweden; as far as I know it can be technically possible but in practice, not really...

Let's expand on this a bit; again, AFAIK, it is not possible to be enrolled to two different masters programs in the same faculty. At least it was not possible when I was in the uni. They might have programs that overlap between different programs and allow you to have a broader portfolio/CV if that is what you desire, but you still get a single degree.

You could try and apply to two different programs at different faculties of the same university. This *may* work, I am not sure if there is a national regulation on that. I would guess that it's handled by individual university administrations.

The last option is of course applying to two different programs at two different universities, so different legal entities. You could try to get into University of Gothenburg and Chalmers for two different programs for example. I cannot imagine why that would not be allowed.

That being said, if you choose to pursue this, you will very likely have crashes on your schedule such that you will not be able to follow the lectures, and potentially miss some compulsory moments of these degrees. Universities typically don't assume the students do more than 100% studies so you will almost certainly have serious incompatibilities on your schedule.

If you are seriously considering getting two masters degrees in one go (and I would advise against it), my suggestion would be to offset them with 1 year, so that you start one program and half way into that start another. The motivation behind this is that Masters programs often tend to have lecture-heavy courses first, and project or assignment based courses later.

Comment: Thanks! That‘s what i was wondering. Would be different faculties probably. One more question: is there any regulation on the amount of time take to finish one master degree? To be more specific: Can i finish in three years instead of two without any punishment?

Comment: @user526159 while I was enrolled in the uni, that's about 10 years ago now, there was no such limit. The only limit I can think of is that the tests (exams) you pass during the studies are only valid for a some years but extending your masters by 1 year should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the Netherlands this is no problem. EU/EER students pay the same tuition fee as Dutch students. Additionally, you only pay once, no matter for how many programmes at how many institutions you enroll (unless you already have a master's degree, in which case you pay higher fees).

I share the concerns in [this other answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/134179/25112). Finishing two masters at the same time without delay is possible, but it is not a pleasant experience.